# Не могу передать данные в View

Tags: php, mvc

Всем привет. Учусь создавать простую MVC. Возникла проблема с передачей данных в шаблон. 
Class View

```
class View
{
    public function render($content, $params = [])
    {
        $content=$content.'.php';
        include 'temlate.php';
    }

}
```

Контроллер

```
 public function index()
    {
        $products = $this->model->showAll();
        return $this->view->render('table', $products);
    }
```

и 2 шаблона

template.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head> 


</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8 offset-2">
            <h4>Content</h4>

            <?php include $content;   ?>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

и table.php

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Image</th>
        <th scope="col">Created</th>
        <th scope="col">Owner</th>
        <th scope="col">Amount_review</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <?php foreach ($products

        as $product): ?>
        <td><a href="show.php/<?php echo $product['id']?>"><?php echo $product['name'] ?></a></td>
        <td><?php echo $product['email'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $product['created_at'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $product['author'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $product['amount_review'] ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>


    </tbody>
    <a href="/form_product.php" class="btn btn-info btn-block">Add new product </a>
</table>
```

Выводит только заголовок таблицы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public function index()
    {
        $products = $this->model->showAll();
        return $this->view->render('table', ['products' => $products]);
    }

    public function render($content, $params = [])
    {

        extract($params);
        $content=$content.'.php';
        include 'temlate.php';
    }
```

Это самое примитивное решение.
У Вас проблема в том что Вы по факту передаете в своё представление $params масив а не $products

Comment: Добавлю только, что в этом случаях бустрее и продуктивнее самостоятельно вставить в код table.php `var_dump($products)` и посмотреть, что там есть и почему цикл не отрабатывает, чем задавать такой вопрос на ruSO в надежде, что кто-то быстро кинется разбираться в длинном коде. В среднем длинным кодом заинтересуются и посмотрят вопрос через несколько часов. За это время можно самостоятельно отладить кучу кода.

Comment: Когда только всё изучаешь, сложно понять почему результат не такой как ожидаешь. Жаль что у нас не было такой возможности при изучении спросить у кого то в инете "Почему")

Comment: Может, именно поэтому мы здесь больше отвечаем, чем спрашиваем, что научились искать ответы самостоятельно, ставить собственные эксперименты и перепроверять каждый шаг? Особенно когда работаешь с легаси-системами с классами в 2000 строк, написаными на незнакомом фреймворке, и надо относительно быстро пофиксить баг, о котором известно только, что он есть, но неизвестно, как его воспроизвести?